# My crystal report does not filter the records in the run time vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

```
   Private Sub Print_insurance_due_sum_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Nothing
        Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
        cryRpt.Load(Application.StartupPath + "/ReportInsuranceDueSummary.rpt")
        Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
        Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
     Dim crParameterValues As New ParameterValues
    Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue
    crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = insid
    crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
    crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("insid")
crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues
crParameterValues.Clear()
crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue1)
crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

this is my code, and the parameters are passing to my CrystalReportViewer1 but the problem is that the records are not filtering according to my conditions in the report
Anyyy helppp !!??
thank You

Comment: Are you using integrated security for the connection to the database ?